# Finding the hex code sequence for a key combination

Tags: vim, hex, tmux

I am trying to understand the way for generating the hex code sequence for keyboard key combinations. So I can use those to send specific keys to a vim session running inside tmux which is inside iTerm2 through the "Send Hex Code" functionality of iTerm2. However, this is becoming extremely confusing.

I have started with this article: [iTerm2 keymaps for tmux](http://tangledhelix.com/blog/2012/04/28/iterm2-keymaps-for-tmux/)

So, as a constant and as a starting point I know that `CTRL-b` can be represented as a hex code of `0x02`.

I have tested that, and it works, when I map this to any random key in iTerm2, I can see that it is sent to tmux as `CTRL-b`

But how do I know the hex code of other key combinations, for example what is the hex code for SHIFT-F10? or CTRL-F5? or CTRL-m-Space?

I have asked another question related to this question here:
[Key escape sequences not working for tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321804/key-escape-sequences-not-working-for-tmux)

Answer (score 25):

You can use the command-line tool `xxd` for this. It reads from `STDIN` and outputs a hex dump alongside the original input, like so:

```
$ echo -n "hello world" | xxd
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 64              hello world
```

Another handy trick to know is that if you want to enter a control character directly, you can often switch to a temporary "raw mode" by prefixing the key/s by `Ctrl-V` (`^V`). For instance, to get the hex codes that represent `Ctrl-b`, run `xxd`, hit `Ctrl-v`, then `Ctrl-b`, then `Enter` (to visually separate the input from `xxd`'s output), then `Ctrl-d` to send an `EOF`:

```
$ xxd
^B
0000000: 020a                                     ..
```

The output can be interpreted like so:

- first column (`0000000`) is the offset
- then we see `02`, which represents `^B`
- next is `0a` (`LF` / `\n`)
- and in the final column we see the original input corresponding with the hex output (dots in this case indicate non-visible characters)

Testing F5 and Shift-F5 on Linux, inside tmux:

```
$ xxd
^[[15~
^[[25~
0000000: 1b5b 3135 7e0a 1b5b 3235 7e0a            .[15~..[25~.
```

So to interpret F5 - we see ESC (`0x1b`), followed by hex representations of the listed characters, terminated by a LF (`0x0a`):

- `5b`, or the [ symbol
- `31`, or the number 1
- `35`, or the number 5
- `7e`, or the ~ symbol

Shift-F5 can be interpreted similarly, except the ANSI sequence uses 25 instead of 15.

You can also use the `tput` command, see the following answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53589

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am testing this now. My issue is that I am not getting a healthy signal flow from the outside world into the terminal world. For example, in the case above, inside iTerm2, when I run `xxd -p` and then do `CTRL-v` followed by `F5`, I get `^[[15~` and a hex code. However, when I do `CTRL-v` followed by `CTRL-F5`, I get `^[[15~`  and a hex. So exactly the same result. This is really bizarre?! :(

Comment: inside the OSX native terminal I get `^[[15~` for `F5` and `^[[25~` for `SHIFT-F5` but nothing for `CTRL-F5`, actually for `CTRL-F5` I get `^M` after an enter. So it seems like all these terminals have their own way of interpreting the keyboard signals, which is confusing.

Comment: Addendum: use `xxd -psg` instead, and you don't have to enter `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl-D` -- just enter what you want, and press enter. Note that the output is going to be slightly different. Source: https://aaronaddleman.com/articles/hexcodes-and-iterm/

Comment: `then we see 20, which represents ^B` I think that `20` is actually `02`

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any way (that I've found yet) to get xxd to output the hex codes for hotkeys involving Cmd on mac. I've mapped Cmd to be Ctrl in iterm, so I can use Cmd with vim/tmux hotkeys that normally use the Ctrl key, but for copy/paste I want Cmd to remain as Cmd for everything in iterm, so I need to add a couple hotkeys in iterm that listen for when Ctrl + c/Ctrl + v are pressed (even tho I'm using the Cmd key to do so) and then output the correct hex codes for Cmd + c/Cmd + v... anyone deal with something similar before?