# Key escape sequences not working for tmux

Tags: vim, hex, macvim, tmux

I have been using **iTerm2** and **vim** for a while. I have experienced some issues when I needed to use key combinations such as *CTRL-F10* and *SHIFT-F10* inside a **vim** session running inside **iTerm2**. It is straight forward to define key bindings such as `<C-F10>` and `<S-F10>` for the GUI version of MacVim. No problems there.

However, it proved to be difficult to get the same key combinations in the terminal version of **MacVim**. I have solved this by using **iTerm2**'s `Send Escape Sequence` functionality. Once I have defined *CTRL-F10* as `[21;5~` and *SHIFT-F10* as `[21;2~` in my iTerm2 profile, those were now working inside the terminal MacVim without any issues.

Recently, I have hit a new wall, when I decided to add **tmux** to the equation. I have noticed that those escape sequences are no longer working for a terminal **MacVim** running inside a **tmux** pane. That is my problem.

I have been focusing on the `Send Hex Code` option, which seems to be working. I tested it with some known hex codes such as `0x04` which is `Ctrl-d` and it works. The problem is that I could not find the hex codes for CTRL-F10 and SHIFT-F10.

So the solution is either make **tmux** receive my escape codes coming from **iTerm2** or find the hex codes for the keys that I need to be working inside tmux.